# Why is IDA showing three arguments for the main function instead of two in some linux binaries?

Tags: ida, x86, elf

So I am reversing an ELF‌ binary, now from my knowledge in C the main function has two argument, argc and argv

but some linux binaries that i am reversing have 3 when i decompile them! one int and the other two are char**, i assume the second is the argv but what is the last one?

one example is this binary for a CTF‌:‌

https://github.com/SPRITZ-Research-Group/ctf-writeups/tree/master/0x00ctf-2017/reverse/challenge-000-50

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does IDA show wrong function arguments in pseudocode?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17872/why-does-ida-show-wrong-function-arguments-in-pseudocode)

Comment: Not a dupe, the arguments are detected correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third one is an array to environment variables that this program has access to. If you read the documentation of [execve](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) it reads as follows:

> The argument vector and environment can be accessed by the called
>    program's main function, when it is defined as:
>
> `int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])`
>
> Note, however, that the use of a third argument to the main function
>    is not specified in POSIX.1; according to POSIX.1, the environment
>    should be accessed via the external variable environ(7).

Comment: So this third argument thing is   used in linux systems and not in widnows, and is added by the compiler correct?

Comment: That would be my understanding too.